# Meteor not starting due to Meteorite package (setting up an older Meteor version with Meteorite packages)

Tags: meteor, package, meteorite

Everyone,

I've got a Meteor project running 0.5.9. I want to setup Meteor 0.5.9 locally as well as Meteorite (since I use some mrt packages).

I've done a clean install of Meteorite on a vagrant server. Running mrt command throws this error:

> $ mrt
>
> Stand back while Meteorite does its thing
>
> Installing Meteor
>
> tag: https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git#v0.5.9
>
> Installing smart packages
>
> child process timed out, no activity for 15 seconds
>
> ERROR: null Command failed: remote: Counting objects: 56555, done.
>   remote: Compressing objects: 100% (17136/17136), done. remote: Total
>   56555 (delta 39097), reused 56241 (delta 38865) Receiving objects:
>   100% (56555/56555), 19.19 MiB | 2.34 MiB/s, done. Resolving deltas:
>   100% (39097/39097), done.
>
> STDOUT: Cloning into
>   '/home/vagrant/.meteorite/source/meteor/meteor'...
>
> STDERR: remote: Counting objects: 56555, done. remote: Compressing
>   objects: 100% (17136/17136), done. remote: Total 56555 (delta 39097),
>   reused 56241 (delta 38865) Receiving objects: 100% (56555/56555),
>   19.19 MiB | 2.34 MiB/s, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (39097/39097), done.
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:124
>           throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url +
>                                                                 ^ There was a problem cloning repo: https://github.com/meteor/meteor.git
>   Please check
>   https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#troubleshooting
>   for potential explanations.

After running `mrt` for a second time, I get this error:

> Downloading Meteor development bundle
>
> ################################################################## 100.0%
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/meteor.js:88
>             throw "Command exited with " + code + "/" + signal;
>                                                       ^ Command exited with 1/null

Running it again, I get:

> Stand back while Meteorite does its thing ✓ router
>       tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.4.3 child process timed out, no activity for 15 seconds
>
> ERROR: null Command failed: remote: Reusing existing pack: 706, done.
>   remote: Total 706 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) Receiving objects:
>   100% (706/706), 123.70 KiB, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (372/372),
>   done.
>
> STDOUT: Cloning into
>   '/home/vagrant/.meteorite/source/tmeasday/meteor-router'...
>
> STDERR: remote: Reusing existing pack: 706, done. remote: Total 706
>   (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0) Receiving objects: 100% (706/706),
>   123.70 KiB, done. Resolving deltas: 100% (372/372), done.
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:124
>           throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url +
>                                                                 ^ There was a problem cloning repo:
>   https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git Please check
>   https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#troubleshooting
>   for potential explanations.

And then this again:

> Stand back while Meteorite does its thing ✓ router
>       tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router.git#v0.4.3 ✓ page-js-ie-support
>       tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js-ie-support.git#v1.3.5 child
>   process timed out, no activity for 15 seconds
>
> ERROR: null Command failed: remote: Reusing existing pack: 46, done.
>   remote: Total 46 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> STDOUT: Cloning into
>   '/home/vagrant/.meteorite/source/tmeasday/meteor-page-js-ie-support'...
>
> STDERR: remote: Reusing existing pack: 46, done. remote: Total 46
>   (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/sources/git.js:124
>           throw "There was a problem cloning repo: " + self.url +
>                                                                 ^ There was a problem cloning repo:
>   https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js-ie-support.git Please check
>   https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#troubleshooting
>   for potential explanations.

Then finally, I keep getting this error:

> Stand back while Meteorite does its thing ✓ page-js-ie-support
>       tag: https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-page-js-ie-support.git#v1.3.5
>
> Done installing smart packages
>
> Ok, everything's ready. Here comes Meteor!
>
> [[[[[ ~/myprojdir ]]]]]
>
> Running on: localhost:3000/ No dependency info in bundle.
>   Filesystem monitoring disabled. Errors prevented startup: Exception
>   while bundling application: Error: Can't set DOCTYPE here.  (Meteor
>   sets  for you) - line 1, file
>   /home/vagrant/myprojdir/packages/page-js-ie-support/page-js/examples/album/index.html
>   
>       at html_scanner.scan.parseError (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/packages/templating/html_scanner.js:23:14)
>       at Object.html_scanner.scan (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/packages/templating/html_scanner.js:58:17)
>       at /home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/packages/templating/package.js:46:32
>       at _.extend.add_file (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/app/lib/bundler.js:206:5)
>       at self.api.add_files (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/app/lib/bundler.js:107:16)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>       at self.api.add_files (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/app/lib/bundler.js:106:11)
>       at Array.forEach (native)
>       at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>       at Object.self.api.add_files (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/app/lib/bundler.js:105:9)
>       at _.extend.init_from_app_dir [as on_use_handler] (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/app/lib/packages.js:139:11)
>       at _.extend.use (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/app/lib/bundler.js:391:11)
>       at Object.exports.bundle (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/app/lib/bundler.js:721:12)
>       at /home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/app/meteor/run.js:613:26
>       at exports.inFiber (/home/vagrant/.meteorite/meteors/meteor/meteor/45fef52095bb6726cc1b2f05008ad891c446100a/app/lib/fiber-helpers.js:22:12)
>
> Please fix the problem and restart.
>
> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/meteorite/lib/command.js:35
>             throw "Command exited with " + code + "/" + signal;
>                                                       ^ Command exited with 1/null

Comment: Added details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453883/mrt-not-starting-due-to-issue-cloning-repo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this was a bit tricky due to non-obvious errors.

Meteorite is great for getting different versions of meteor. Since I wanted meteor 0.5.9, I figured it would be as easy as installing meteorite and letting 'er rip! Not so much, as you can see from the errors in the question.

After almost giving up, I thought, hey since I'm looking for Meteor 0.5.9, I should try and install the version of meteorite that was available at that time!

In the [meteorite github page](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite), I found that the  branch `0.5.9` was pretty closely released with meteor version 0.5.9. So, I downloaded the zipped version of that meteorite branch and unzipped it in my machine.

Then I installed it using npm:

```
sudo npm install -g meteorite-0.5.9
```

Then, I ran `mrt` in my app directory and just like that, it worked! :D

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to 0.8.1.1, I had certain packages that didn't work.  Finally figured out that now I have to do certain mrt add commands as the superuser.  (sudo mrt add iron-router).

For whatever it's worth